# How to return only all parent sections?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, backend, nestjs

I'm using Nestjs for my backend and I'm trying to create an api call that return only all the parent sections but not sure how to do that so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

Entity

```
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        type: "int",
        name: "Id",
    })
    id: number;

    @Column("nvarchar", {
        nullable: false,
        unique: true,
        name: "Name"
    })
    name: string;

    @Column("nvarchar", {
        nullable: false,
        name: "ParentId"
    })
    parentId: number;
```

Controller

```
    @Get('/parentSection')
    async getSectionHelp(@Req() req, @Param() params):Promise<HelpEntity[]>{
        return this.helpService.getHelpbySection(req.user, params.id);
    }
```

Service

```
  constructor(@InjectRepository(HelpEntity) private readonly helpRepo: Repository<HelpEntity>,

    async getHelpbySection(gmid: string, id: number) : Promise<any>{
        let check = await this.checkIfAdmin(gmid);
        if (!check) {
            throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', 401);
        } else {
            const res = await this.helpRepo.find()
            if (!res) {
                throw new NotFoundException(`This ID: ${id} is not found`)
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

In my database all my parent section has NULL in ParentId.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to specify it in the find function:

```
 import {IsNull} from "typeorm";
 ...
 ...
 async getHelpbySection(gmid: string, id: number) : Promise<any>{
    let check = await this.checkIfAdmin(gmid);
    if (!check) {
        throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', 401);
    } else {
        const res = await this.helpRepo.find({parentId: IsNull()})
        if (!res) {
            throw new NotFoundException(`This ID: ${id} is not found`)
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: ah it work. Thank you so much Youba..I really appreicated it.

Comment: Hi Youba..by anychance can you help me out this too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794624/how-to-return-all-the-subsections-that-belong-to-particular-section . I would be really appreciated if you can. thank you

Comment: You're welcome, I just did, you can check it out now