# How to return all the subsections that belong to particular section?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, backend, nestjs

I'm using Nestjs for my backend and I'm trying to create an api call that return all the subsections for particular section but not sure how to do that so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

so if I do Get/subsection/167 (167 is the section Id) then I will get all the subsections for that particular section.

Entity

```
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        type: "int",
        name: "Id",
    })
    id: number;

    @Column("nvarchar", {
        nullable: false,
        unique: true,
        name: "Name"
    })
    name: string;

    @Column("nvarchar", {
        nullable: false,
        name: "ParentId"
    })
    parentId: number;
```

Controller

```
    @Get('/subsection/:parentId')
    async getHelpSubSection(@Req() req, @Param() params):Promise<HelpEntity[]>{
        return this.helpService.getHelpbySubSection(req.user, params.id);
    }
```

Service

```
  constructor(@InjectRepository(HelpEntity) private readonly helpRepo: Repository<HelpEntity>,

    async getHelpbySubSection(gmid: string, id: number) : Promise<any>{
        let check = await this.checkIfAdmin(gmid);
        if (!check) {
            throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', 401);
        } else {
            const res = await this.helpRepo.findOne()
            if (!res) {
                throw new NotFoundException(`This ID: ${id} is not found`)
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

In my database all my parent section has NULL in ParentId.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to edit the findone to find with your condition:

```
 constructor(@InjectRepository(HelpEntity) private readonly helpRepo: Repository<HelpEntity>,

async getHelpbySubSection(gmid: string, id: number) : Promise<any>{
    let check = await this.checkIfAdmin(gmid);
    if (!check) {
        throw new HttpException('Unauthorized', 401);
    } else {
        const res = await this.helpRepo.find({parentId : id})
        if (!res) {
            throw new NotFoundException(`This ID: ${id} is not found`)
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

**Update** 
and in your controller fix the name of the param

```
  @Get('/subsection/:parentId')
async getHelpSubSection(@Req() req, @Param() params):Promise<HelpEntity[]>{
    return this.helpService.getHelpbySubSection(req.user, params.parentId);
}
```

for more details please check : [find-options](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md)

Comment: Hi Youba, thanks for this but when I tried it, it only returning empty array. it doesn't returning all the subsections for the particular section. any idea?

Comment: try to do .find({ where: { parentId : id } });

Comment: sady I tried it but I'm still getting only this, [ ].  it's not returning any subsection not sure why.

Comment: can you verify what 'id' return?

Comment: check this one, change nvarchar to int @Column("int", {
        nullable: false,
        name: "ParentId"
    })
    parentId: number;

Comment: id is returning undefined. not sure why. I also change the nvarchar to int but still not working. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224483/discussion-between-youba-and-aase-zi).

Comment: It work, thank you so much for your help again. really appreciated it.